# How to filter non-ultraviolet portions of the EM spectrum on a camera (Eg, needing a UV pass filter)?

Tags: filters, uv

I am assembling a project wherein I will be using a full spectrum camera that captures from around 250nm on up into infrared. My goal is to primarily work within the lower wavelength (ultraviolet) / higher energy portion of the spectrum from 400nm down to 250nm, which is the lower bound on this camera.

I have been trying to find a filter (specifically a 37mm filter) that would limit this so that I could primarily work down in the lower wavelength, but I have really been at a loss thus far.

How would one go about either constructing or finding some kind of a UV pass filter such as this that has a higher range rather than highly specific wavelength parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I was having a problem finding this initially due to my lack of full understanding of what the filter would accomplish and some missing terminology.  Ultimately I did end up finding a pre-built lens that accomplishes my goals quite well.

There are two filters actually that would do the trick.  One is a UV pass filter and the other is a UV + IR pass filter.  The latter ends up actually serving my needs a little better and has the following wavelength filtering characteristics:

[image: UV and UV + IR Filter Graph]
(As per http://www.maxmax.com/aXRayTechnical.htm)

I found the second XNiteUVR a little more to my liking due to passing through both the UV and the IR around the visible portion of the spectrum.

Additionally this is available as a 37mm lens and was thrilled to see that they have reasonable prices on their [order page](http://www.maxmax.com/aXRayIRFilterOrderMain.htm).

Answer (score 1):

UV-pass filters are commercially available. Just a quick look in Amazon found [52mm UV Black #403 Glass Filter for Type "A" Ultra Violet Transmission](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012C5L4K) and B&H Photo has  [Rosco Permacolor Glass UV Pass Woods-type Filter - 2" Round](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/189951-REG/Rosco_120336507495_Permacolor_UV_Woods.html). [Edmund Optics](http://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-filters/bandpass-filters/colored-glass-bandpass-filters/1924/) has pages of glass filters.

It will take some work to find one with acceptable transmission in the bands you want, and you might need to use sapphire for short-wave UV, rather than glass. If you do not find a 37 mm filter, you can use adapter rings or a filter holder (the Amazon filter is 52 mm).

Comment: Hey thanks! That's some really good information and sheds some additional light on my understanding!  I ended up finding one that matched my needs earlier today and have posted that here as well.